# Updating DatagridView Image Column in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm trying to get a datagridview updated that is populated by the datatable.

When launching it shows the image of (Properties.Resources.database) and not (Properties.Resources.completed).

```
        DataTable dtStores = new DataTable();
        dtStores.Columns.Add("Total");
        dtStores.Columns.Add("Store");
        dtStores.Columns.Add("Status",typeof(Image));

        DataRow rStore = dtStores.NewRow();
        rStore["Total"] = "";
        rStore["Store"] = "Supermarket";
        rStore["Status"] = Properties.Resources.database;
        dtStores.Rows.Add(rStore);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtStores;
        
        DataGridViewRow dGRVStore = dataGridView1.Rows[0];

        DataGridViewImageCell imgStatus = new DataGridViewImageCell();

        imgStatus.Value = Properties.Resources.completed;
        dGRVStore.Cells["Status"] = imgStatus ; dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: The DGV is bound to a DataTable, so update the value stored in the DataTable not the DGV.

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I want to capture all the data in the grid is to modify and display to the user, without modifying the DT and rebinding it. I can do with with text like dGRVStore.Cells["Total"].Value = "5"; but it there  way for images?

Comment: One way I found was this.. dataGridView1["Status", 0].Value = Properties.Resources.completed;

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1["Status", 0].Value = Properties.Resources.completed;